# jquery $.when not working by waiting function in master page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .when

i have some problem when i use jquery.when function in web form using master page

This is my code in web form using master page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.when(masterPageFunction()).done(function(){
     webFormFunction();
  });
})
```

And this my master page

```
function masterPageFunction() {
   //In this function i call 2 ajax like this
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/api/master/xxx/",
         data: JSON.stringify(obj),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) {
               $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/api/master/xxx2/",
                        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {

                        }
              })
         }
   })
}
```

result is web function is running when master page function not done 
please help, thank you so much

Comment: Why are you using the same parameter for two separate Ajax calls, but do absolutely nothing with the response from either?  And why not separate them?  Since it will already perform asynchronously?

Comment: it's just example.

Comment: We need more information, the example does not provide enough detail.

Comment: Also I believe you want to return a promise, but the way your code is structure won't work the way intended.  You may be mixing up asynchronous function with the promise.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but the `when`, `then` and `done` functions rely on promises. You aren't returning any promises in your code, so it's just running straight through.

First, you'll need to obtain the result of the promise after it completes in the `done` function in your master page. We'll do that by adding a `response` parameter to the callback, then passing it through to `webFormFunction`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.when(masterPageFunction()).done(function(response){
     webFormFunction(response);
  });
})
```

Next, we need to add a promise to `masterPageFunction` and return it. You resolve the promise with the response you want to send back to the `done` function in your master page. Like so:

```
function masterPageFunction() {

    // Create the promise
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    //In this function i call 2 ajax like this
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/master/xxx/",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/master/xxx2/",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    // Resolve the promise with the response from $.ajax
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Return the promise (It hasn't been resolved yet!)
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

In this way, `webFormFunction` won't be called until the second ajax call completes, which resolves the promise.